# Cannot write bytes: Broken pipe

Tags: 12.04, boot

I uninstalled 11.04 and installed 12.04 and grub was not detecting the partitions, so I fixed it with boot-repair and 12.04 loaded perfectly, then I tried to install the device driver for Nvidia Graphics card and it took a long time, so I stopped it and shut down.When I restarted the computer I got the message cannot write bytes: broken pipe.Then I followed this thread for help.
[could not write bytes broken pipe 12.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/355515/could-not-write-bytes-broken-pipe-12-04)

I went to recovery mode and drooping to root prompt and typed this command

```
sudo gedit /var/log/apt/history.log
```

For this I got the following error message as gedit did not open that file:

```
(gedit : 856):Warning : Command line 'dbus-launch --autolaunch=somernadomnumbers --
binary-syntax --close-stderr' exitted with non-zero exit 
status 1: Autolaunch error: X11 initialization failed. \n
cannot open display:
Run 'gedit --help' to see a full list of available command options.
```

Did this happen because of stopping the installation of Nvidia device driver in the middle of its installation?

I am running 12.04 with Winodws 7 dual boot.Any help would be appreciated.

When 12.04 was working normally I started and quit in the middle of the installation of the Grahpics driver for Nvidia Grahpics card and I restarted the computer and got the could not write bytes: broken pipe error.

Comment: No the error was not because you stopped the installation, it was because gedit cannot be opened in recovery mode. You should try to use command-line based test-editors like nano or vim. When exactly do you get the broken pipe error? Please edit you question to post the answer.

Comment: I have added at the end of the question, the point at which I got the broken pipe error.

Answer (score 0):

A quick fix: boot in recovery mode with networking and issue `sudo apt-get install --reinstall xserver-xorg`, then reboot.