# Canon printer Unable to write print data - Broken pipe

Tags: drivers, printing, canon

I would like to ask about issue with Canon I-Sensys printer installation on Ubuntu 20.04 (but I think, the simmilar issue is often, because I found a few threads about it also here in askubuntu).

After successfully installation of Canon ISensys 7200 CAPT driver, version 2.71 from here:
https://www.canon.sk/support/consumer_products/products/printers/laser/i-sensys_lbp7200cdn.html?type=drivers&language=en&os=linux%20(64-bit)

(installation was success without any problems), I found the right driver in the list and I added a new printer:

## Step1

[image]

## Step2

[image]

## Step3

[image]

## Step4

[image]

Everything was done without any problems. But, when I want to print text from editor or printer test page, still I have same error:

**Unable to write print data: Broken pipe**

[image]

I found a few threads about, for example like following, I tried to reinstall xserver-xorg in ubuntu safe mode, but it doesnt help me:

[Cannot write bytes: Broken pipe](https://askubuntu.com/questions/404208/cannot-write-bytes-broken-pipe)

Also I was calling to the Canon support, but there is nobody to support linux :-(

Thanks a lot for each help.

Answer (score 0):

*Broken pipe* is from CUPS. Step 2 indicates you are using the URI `socket://192.168.7.11:9100`. This is OK, as a socket URI is generally very reliable. Do a quick check of the connection with `telnet 192.168.7.11 9100`.

In addition to a URI a PPD is needed. `lpinfo -m | grep -i 7200C` should allow you to find one. What I would then do is set up a print queue with `sudo lpadmon -p 7200c -v "URI" -E -m "PPD"`, substituting for URI and PPD of course.

Test with `lp -d 7200c /etc/nsswitch.conf`.

Another URI (probably dnssd://...) should be obtainable from `lpinfo -v`. It coul be tried in place of socket://... .

Comment: Hi @brian_p, thanks a lot, for the help. telnet is working and Im able to connect to the printer

Comment: result of lpinfo -m | grep -i 7200C is:
CNCUPSLBP7200CCAPTJ.ppd Canon LBP7200C CAPT (JP)
lsb/usr/CNCUPSLBP7200CCAPTJ.ppd Canon LBP7200C CAPT (JP)
CNCUPSLBP7200CCAPTK.ppd Canon LBP7200C CAPT (UK)
lsb/usr/CNCUPSLBP7200CCAPTK.ppd Canon LBP7200C CAPT (UK)
CNCUPSLBP7200CCAPTS.ppd Canon LBP7200C CAPT (US)
lsb/usr/CNCUPSLBP7200CCAPTS.ppd Canon LBP7200C CAPT (US)

Comment: sudo lpadmon -p 7200c -v "URI" -E -m "PPD": If I understand correctly, I put to the concole this: sudo lpadmin -p 7200c -v "socket://192.168.1.11:9100" -E -m "lsb/usr/CNCUPSLBP7200CCAPTS.ppd" and result is: lpadmin: Printer drivers are deprecated and will stop working in a future version of CUPS.

Comment: lp -d 7200c /etc/nsswitch.conf - result is: request id is 7200c-57 (1 file(s)) Thanks a lot for your help :-)

Comment: @acqsk Everything you have done looks fine. But did you get ink put on paper?

Comment: No :-( Still I have the same error and printer does not start printing.

Comment: @acqsk I have updated my answer.

Comment: Hi Brian, thanks a lot for your help, result of lpinfo -d is: network socket
file cups-pdf:/
network lpd
direct ccp
network ipps
file cups-brf:/
network beh
network https
network http
network ipp
network smb
direct hp
direct hpfax
network socket://192.168.1.11

Comment: I tiried sudo lpadmin -p 7200c -v "dnssd://192.168.1.11:9100" -E -m "lsb/usr/CNCUPSLBP7200CCAPTS.ppd", result is the same, like before: lpadmin: Printer drivers are deprecated and will stop working in a future version of CUPS.

Comment: ...and result of lp -d 7200c /etc/nsswitch.conf is also the same: request id is 7200c-69 (1 file(s))

Comment: ...and printer is in my home, next to me, turned on, paper inside, from Windows in the same notebook (dualboot) printing is working, from Ubuntu no.